Can't upgrade from 22.04.04 to 24.04.01
I want to upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04, but I'm not getting the upgrade notification.
I've tried upgrading manually from the CLI, but when I run do-release-upgrade I get this message:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

Here is the output of lsb_release -a:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Seems to me that I should be able to run the upgrade. What am I missing, are they using phased rollout for upgrading?

Upgrade to 24.04 from 22.04 paused. See https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/09/canonical-halts-ubuntu-24-04-lts-upgrades-again

Or search this site this has been asked many many many times.

Have you tried the steps outlined in this post?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1512697/an-easy-way-to-upgrade-from-22-04-to-24-04-without-losing-data-or-application-se

According to documentation, you should get the upgrade notification because you can directly upgrade from 22.04.x LTS, when 24.04.1 LTS will be available.
But something goes wrong. I had the same.
Anyway, you can open "Software & Updates" -> Tab "Updates" -> Raw "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" -> Change "For long-term support versions" to "For any new version".
After checking new updates you will get an upgrade notification.
